# customizing each scene with adMobs

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

i'm using admobs to show ads in my scene. i'm adding the bannerview in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method in the ViewController. The problem is this seem to be added in all the scenes, where i only wanted it added to one of the scenes.

This is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    //skView.showsFPS = YES;
    //skView.showsNodeCount = YES;


    if (!skView.scene) {

        self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
        self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-5705189099471387/1882864952";
        self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
        self.bannerView.delegate = self;
        self.bannerView.center = CGPointMake(skView.bounds.size.width / 2, skView.bounds.size.height - (bannerView_.frame.size.height / 2));
        [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
        GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
        r.testing = YES;
        [self.bannerView loadRequest:r];
        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [Menu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

        NSLog(@"%@", scene);

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];


    }

}



-(void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"Ad Reveived");

    adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);

}

-(GADRequest *)createRequest {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
    return request;
}
```

Comment: That's because scenes aren't views. Call a method on your view controller when switching scenes that handles enabling/disabling of the ad banner view.

Comment: Well what would be the solution for this. am i going to call the bannerView differently or what can i do?